# Infinite top-to-bottom pure CSS Photo Banner, stack on first image

Tags: css, html, css-animations

I'm trying to make a pure css top to bottom infinite photo banner (without any margins) with ability to use scrsets for larger displays and zooming (css background url is not an option for this case).

1. I can't figure it out how to calculate all the numbers that is necessary for the animation, can someone explain it to me, please?
   1.1. What do I have to change if I add more images to the div?
2. The first frame is not moving (second frame suddenly "eats" the first one), why is it happening and how to fix it?
3. What am I doing wrong?

This is what I'm done so far:

```css
#container {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: white;
    margin: 0;
} 
.photobanner {
    height: 466px;
    width: 350px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    background-color: blue;
}
.photobanner img{
    display: block;
}    
.first {
 -webkit-animation: bannermove 30s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: bannermove 30s linear infinite;
     -ms-animation: bannermove 30s linear infinite;
      -o-animation: bannermove 30s linear infinite;
         animation: bannermove 30s linear infinite;
}
 
@keyframes "bannermove" {
 0% {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
 }
 100% {
    margin-bottom: -466px;
 }
 
}
 
@-moz-keyframes bannermove {
 0% {
   margin-bottom: 0px;
 }
 100% {
   margin-bottom: -466px;
 }
 
}
 
@-webkit-keyframes "bannermove" {
 0% {
   margin-bottom: 0px;
 }
 100% {
   margin-bottom: -466px;
 }
 
}
 
@-ms-keyframes "bannermove" {
 0% {
   margin-bottom: 0px;
 }
 100% {
   margin-bottom: -466px;
 }
 
}
 
@-o-keyframes "bannermove" {
 0% {
   margin-bottom: 0px;
 }
 100% {
   margin-bottom: -466px;
 }
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
</head>

<body>


<div id="container">    
<!-- Each image is 350px by 233px -->
<div class="photobanner">
<img class="first" src="https://dummyimage.com/350x233/000/fff.png&text=1" alt="" />
<img src="https://dummyimage.com/350x233/000/fff.png&text=1" alt="" />
<img src="https://dummyimage.com/350x233/000/fff.png&text=2" alt="" />
<img src="https://dummyimage.com/350x233/000/fff.png&text=1" alt="" />

</div>
</div>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I would recommend that you avoid using pixel values. If you want this to be responsive you will need to use percentage values

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this example](https://codepen.io/ijackson/pen/vzEXyW) I have created. I am using 3 separate images.

For this to work, I used images which are all of the same size.

Each image is 350 x 150 so from that I can determine the height/width ratio to be 0.4285

The ratio value can be used as padding to specify the height of the carousel - This trick can be used to create a responsive carousel:

```
.carousel {
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 43%;
}
```

This will allow the carousel to scale in proportion with the images.

Since we want the carousel to be infinite scrolling, it needs to have a duplicate of the first slide at the bottom. This will allow the animation to continue seamlessly.

The animation itself is manipulating the `transform` value between `0%` and `75%`. I am using 75 here because there are a total of 4 images in the carousel and we want the animation to loop at the 3rd quarter of the progression.

If we have 3 images, we would need to change this value to `66.66%`